# Как короче записать цикл от 0 до 100?

Tags: c++, олимпиада

Если учитывать пробелы, то минимум, что получилось у меня:

```
for(int i;i<100;i++)
```

Работает корректно, поэтому сразу вопрос, кто `i` поставил значение 0, компилятор?

P.S. Объявить зарание что-то, к примеру переменную `i`, или изменять её в цикле нельзя (точнее можно, но это будет считаться за символы)

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74752/discussion-on-question-by--------0--100).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В разделе 6.5.3 стандарта ничего об отдельной инициализации в цикле `for` не говорится, но из текста ясно, что переменная счетчика по сути представляет собой локальную переменную, так что инициализация нулем если и делается, то как расширение конкретного компилятора.

*"По-моему, так" (с) Пух*

Что до самой краткой записи цикла... Короче чем

```
for(int i=100;i--;)
```

у меня пока не придумалось.

Comment: бесокнечный цикл?

Comment: Но это не цикл от 0 до 100, а цикл от 99 до 0.

Comment: Вот вы привереды) for(int i=101;--i;)

Comment: @AnT Так ведь и у ТС - от 0 до 99... :) А направление вряд ли критично в данной задаче.